# Как исправить ошибку в Gulp выдается ошибка Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module, к какой версии gulp-size следует откатиться?

Tags: gulp, npm

Как исправить ошибку в `Gulp`? 
Выдается ошибка:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module,

к какой версии `gulp-size` следует откатиться?

Answer (score 0):

Это - довольно простой вопрос,
отыскиваете репозиторий пакета https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-size, переходите к релизам https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-size/releases, находите версию с сообщением о переходе на ESM и версию, предшествующую ей,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам нужна установка версии v4.0.1.